# traverse XML tree to get attribute value

Tags: xml, xpath, simplexml, php

This is my XML (snippet):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test>
    <body label_position="left">
    <page number="1">
        <itemset name="">
        <item name="" id="1" />
        <item name="" id="2" label_position="right" />  
    </itemset>
    </page>
    </body>
</test>
```

**What I want to accomplish:**
Does `<item id="1">` have a `label_position` attribute set?
(1) If so, return it.
(2) If not, check the node's parent for that attribute.
(3) If the parent has the attribute, return it.
(4) If not, go to step (2). `<body>` is the 'oldest' node to be checked.

**What I've tried:**
I am using `simplexml` and `xpath`, and I tried to select `<item>` and all its ancestors and then traverse the tree upwards and stop with the first occurrence of `label_position`.

```
$xml->xpath("//item[@id='1']::ancestors-or-self/@label_position");
```

produced an `invalid expression`.

(1) How do I get this expression working?
(2) Could this be done with "xpath-only" - without traversing the tree and do the search?

**EDIT: Thanks to choroba & dirkk, I was able to put it together:**

```
$test = (string)array_reverse($xml->xpath("//item[@id='2']/ancestor-or-self::*/@label_position"))[0];
```

**Explanation:** if both `<item>` and `<body>` have the attribute, `xpath` will return an array with both values, the `<body>` one first. In this case, I want to get the `<item>` one first, that's why the `array_reverse()`.

see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/jDPIde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be more careful about the XPath syntax. The correct form of your expression is

```
//item[@id='1']/ancestor-or-self::*/@label_position
```

You cannot use `::` after a predicate, and you have to specify `::` after an axis.

Answer (score 2):

Your XPath is invalid. The axis step must be fore the element name, e.g. something like `axis::node`, not the other way round.

The following should work. Your logic already is xpath-only and it is perfectly fine to traverse the tree.

```
(//item[@id='1']/ancestor-or-self::*/@label_position)[last()]
```

Comment: The `/data()` yielded a "invalid expression" though, without that, it works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @michi I updated my XPath to reflect the changes in your edit. You can do this solely with XPath, no need to use `array_reverse`

Comment: really nice one! do need extra line to cast to string, though, see http://codepad.viper-7.com/NflXLz